# How to brew moonshine?

Tags: alcohol

I need to know the equipment and the step by step process, cause i already try do it, but it didn't work

I already watch several videos, but its not the same to talk to someone that really loves , and know how to do it. I don't know anybody that knows how to brew anything

Comment: This is not specific enough, please see our help center topic on [How to ask a good question](https://alcohol.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I ask the same question on stackexchange Homebrewing, and they answer me, if i dont know really anything about that, and i want to know, i think the question is that one, i know its a long one, but its a fair question, that i really wanna know... but ok, thanks anyway

Comment: I am closing this question. It SHOULD be on alcohol.stackexchange.com not in homebrewing. This isn't the distillers stack.

Comment: On alcohol.stackexchange.com they said to ask in here, it was not me that migrate this question

Comment: Im sorry for my mistake anyway, im new here

Comment: I answered your previous question.  What part of the process do you want further explanation of ?  Maybe make a comment on the previous answer.